# How to draw polygons on an existing map?

Tags: java, geotools

If you want a map with some circles, squares, etc. representing cities or something else you can use the following code.

Note that you can change the map and the coordinates with yours, and you'll get your own map in a java application!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.net.URL;
import org.geotools.data.DataUtilities;
import org.geotools.data.shapefile.ShapefileDataStore;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureCollection;
import org.geotools.data.simple.SimpleFeatureSource;
import org.geotools.factory.CommonFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.feature.FeatureCollections;
import org.geotools.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureBuilder;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTSFactoryFinder;
import org.geotools.map.FeatureLayer;
import org.geotools.map.MapContent;
import org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer;
import org.geotools.styling.FeatureTypeStyle;
import org.geotools.styling.Graphic;
import org.geotools.styling.Mark;
import org.geotools.styling.PointSymbolizer;
import org.geotools.styling.PolygonSymbolizer;
import org.geotools.styling.Rule;
import org.geotools.styling.Style;
import org.geotools.styling.StyleBuilder;
import org.geotools.styling.StyleFactory;
import org.geotools.swing.JMapFrame;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeatureType;
import org.opengis.feature.type.GeometryDescriptor;
import org.opengis.filter.FilterFactory;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Coordinate;
import com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryFactory;

public class MyGIS{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            usingFeatureCaching();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void usingFeatureCaching() throws Exception {

        //Shape-file's path
        URL url = new URL("file://C:/PE/Italia/reg2011_g.shp");
        ShapefileDataStore shapefile = new ShapefileDataStore(url);

        // Creates a map and adds the shapefile
        MapContent map = new MapContent();

        //Set's windows title
        map.setTitle("Italy");

        //Creates the map style
        StyleBuilder styleBuilder = new StyleBuilder();
        PolygonSymbolizer restrictedSymb = styleBuilder.createPolygonSymbolizer(Color.LIGHT_GRAY, Color.BLACK, 0);

        //Sets opacity
        restrictedSymb.getFill().setOpacity(styleBuilder.literalExpression(0.5));
        org.geotools.styling.Style myStyle = styleBuilder.createStyle(restrictedSymb);

        //Adds another layer to the map     
        FeatureLayer layer = new FeatureLayer(shapefile.getFeatureSource(), myStyle);
        map.addLayer(layer);

        //-------------------------- BUILDS THE CIRCLE ON THE MAP ------------------------------------------//

        StyleFactory sf = CommonFactoryFinder.getStyleFactory(null);
        FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory2();

        SimpleFeatureSource fs = shapefile.getFeatureSource();

        SimpleFeatureType pointtype = DataUtilities.createType("Location", "the_geom:Point," + "name:String");

        SimpleFeatureBuilder sfb = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(pointtype);

        double longitude = 537319.7867d;
        double latitude = 5062350.2792d;

        GeometryFactory geometryFactory= JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory(null);
        com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
        sfb.add(point);

        SimpleFeatureCollection col = FeatureCollections.newCollection();
        SimpleFeature feature1 = sfb.buildFeature(null);
        col.add(feature1);


        org.geotools.styling.Stroke stroke2 = sf.createStroke(
                ff.literal(new Color(0xC8, 0x46, 0x63)),
                //circle thickness
                ff.literal(1)
        );

        org.geotools.styling.Fill fill2 = sf.createFill(
                ff.literal(new Color(0xff, 0xC8, 0x61)));

        map.setTitle("Italia");


        //Type of symbol
        Mark mark = sf.getCircleMark();

        mark.setFill(fill2);
        mark.setStroke(stroke2);

        Graphic graphic = sf.createDefaultGraphic();
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().clear();
        graphic.graphicalSymbols().add(mark);

        //circle dimension on the map
        graphic.setSize(ff.literal(5));

        GeometryDescriptor geomDesc = fs.getSchema().getGeometryDescriptor();
        String geometryAttributeName = geomDesc.getLocalName();
        PointSymbolizer sym2 = sf.createPointSymbolizer(graphic, geometryAttributeName);

        Rule rule2 = sf.createRule();
        rule2.symbolizers().add(sym2);
        Rule rules2[] = {rule2};
        FeatureTypeStyle fts2 = sf.createFeatureTypeStyle(rules2);
        Style style2 = sf.createStyle();
        style2.featureTypeStyles().add(fts2);

        map.addLayer(new FeatureLayer(col, style2));


        StreamingRenderer renderer = new StreamingRenderer();
        renderer.setMapContent(map);

        //Shows the map 
        JMapFrame.showMap(map);
    }
}
```

This is the result of the code:

[image: The code's result]

PS: [Here](http://nixweb.altervista.org/Map.zip) you can find the complete project, enjoy!

Comment: I've corrected the code and now it works perfectly!

Comment: By editing out your original question it's now unclear what is going on here/what the purpose of this question is. This no longer conforms to the site's Q&A format, and may not help others with similar problems in the future.

Comment: Could you please give the updated link of the complete project. And version of GEOTOOLS you used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've created a while ago a method to draw points on a layer from geotagged flickr pictures.
It shows basically how to create a *FeatureLayer* with custom points

```
public Layer getFlickrLayer(){

    SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder b = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();

    b.setName( "pictures" );
    b.setCRS( DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84 ); 
    //picture location
    b.add( "geom", Point.class );
    //picture url
    b.add( "url", String.class );

    final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = b.buildFeatureType();

    SimpleFeatureCollection collection = FeatureCollections.newCollection("internal");
    WKTReader2 wkt = new WKTReader2();

    for(Photo currentPhoto : this.photoList){

        float lat = currentPhoto.getGeoData().getLatitude();
        float lng = currentPhoto.getGeoData().getLongitude();

        try {
            collection.add( SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{ wkt.read("POINT("+lng+" "+lat+")"), "<<"+currentPhoto.getSmallUrl()+">>"}, null) );
        } catch (ParseException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    Style style = SLD.createPointStyle("Star", Color.BLUE, Color.BLUE, 0.3f, 15);

    Layer flickrLayer = new FeatureLayer(collection, style);

    flickrLayer.setTitle("flickr layer");

    return flickrLayer;

}
```

As you can see the *SimpleFeatureBuilder* can be used to create points. Just use your own lat and lng values and remove the picture url and you create a layer with your custom points. I have also created a style for the points.
You can simply add this layer to your existing map.

In case you do not need a more complex feature points can be created without the well known text method.

```
GeometryFactory geometryFactory = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

Coordinate coordinates = new Coordinate(lat, lng);
Point point = geometryFactory.createPoint(coordinates);
```

Comment: Thank you very much @user1168261! I've edited your code and I think it's fine, but I can't understand why it gives me an error on the collection adding line...

Look at the line with the error:

`collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{ wkt.read("POINT("+lng+" "+lat+")"), null}, null));`

Can you tell me why, please?

Comment: Here you can find the complete code modified by me:

[Modified code](http://www.nixweb.altervista.org/code.java)

Comment: Without the url string in your SimpleFeatureType you don't need a second argument when creating the point. Try collection.add(SimpleFeatureBuilder.build( TYPE, new Object[]{ wkt.read("POINT("+lng+" "+lat+")")}, null));

Comment: Now it works, but there's a problem: the map isn't shown as big as it was without the CitiesLayer. Now when I run the application the geotools windows starts, but is to slow to show the map, and it is also too little to see the points on it! There's also another problem: when I try to zoom in or to darg, it desapears! Can you tell me why?

Comment: I refreshed my code above!

Comment: Try to set another area of interest http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/map/MapContext.html#setAreaOfInterest(org.geotools.geometry.jts.ReferencedEnvelope), basically the extend of your largest layer. You could also add the cities layer first a guess. I do not know why it is so slow. The only thing that comes into my mind is that your shape has a different reference system than the points (WGS84) and the on the fly reprojection is too slow. Figure out the CRS of your shape and set the same for the point layer.

Comment: `FeatureCollections.newCollection()` is deprecated. How do we implement this in newer versions?