# Geotools : A layer to draw the traffic volume of a road

Tags: layers, geotools

I have developed a standalone swing application loaded with a shapefile of a road network using geotools (v.14.3). Now I would like to implement a feature where the user may zoom the map, and at a pre-set zoom level, the traffic volumes of the currently visible road would be drawn close to the road ([Here's a sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZWel.jpg), instead of letters, there would be the traffic volume in a number). Traffic volume is a number which the user would need to take decisions.

I've seen an example [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/46936/how-to-draw-polygons-on-an-existing-map) where they discuss about drawing circles and other polygons on a separate layer on a JmapPane.

How can I draw the traffic volume of the currently zoomed road?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply create an [SLD style](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html) with a `MaxScaleDenominator` set to the value that you want the labels to be added and a `TextSymbolizer` with a reference to the traffic volume attribute. You will probably want to set some of the options listed at the bottom of the TextSymbolizer section of the [documentation](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/render/style.html).